Why some system cmds would be designed (compiled) as shared object type file?
For similarly, the following system cmds all are the same executable files. 
So why some system cmds would be designed as shared object type file ？
# 
# 
# file /usr/bin/passwd
/usr/bin/passwd: setuid ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
# 
# 
# file /usr/bin/who
/usr/bin/who: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
# 
# 
# file /usr/sbin/lvm
/usr/sbin/lvm: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
# 
# 
# file /sbin/ntpdate
/sbin/ntpdate: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, AMD x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
# 
# 


Update: 
Surely I have already known about the difference between the executable and shared object. 
So what I mean is why some system cmds needed to be designed as shared object files (but not executable files) ? 

They are executable, and they’re not designed as DSOs — they just end up that way because they’re position-independent. Newer versions of file provide more useful output on this kind of executable.
